# How to use ssh-add on a remote desktop?

Tags: ssh

Since the client is already sshd, it cannot open a connection to the authentication agent, what is the best way to ssh-add in this situation?

i.e.

```
ssh dev@192.168.0.2
ssh-add
>> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Comment: @Panther this doesn't appear to work. After `eval ssh-agent` both `ssh-add` and `eval ssh-add` still create `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` warning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have agent forwarding set up, and the agent is already running on your local system, you can just open a new terminal and run `ssh-add` in it. The agent process remains the same, so the existing agent forwarding should be able to use newly added keys:

```
# on server
$ git pull
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
# in new terminal
~ ssh-add
Identity added: /home/muru/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/muru/.ssh/id_rsa)
Identity added: /home/muru/.ssh/id_ed25519 (muru@ubuntu.local)
# back to the server tab
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: It doesn't work...maybe I don't have the agent forwarding set up. Is it on by default? If not please elaborate.

Comment: If you don't have agent forwarding set up, there's no purpose to running `ssh-add` for an existing connection. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Git pull on the remote computer without typing the password.

Comment: Then you need to setup agent forwarding. See https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/. You have to set this up when connecting to the remote system.

Comment: Whoops, looks like that page doesn't exist. P.S., never mind, I just need to copy and paste the url.